# How to split iterative tkinter Entry widgets into usable variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create a template for data storage using a class/dict structure that will allow me generate a dictionary of X values and then edit the values in a tkinter window that is set up to generate X entry widgets.

So far I have been able to create the window and generate the entry boxes, labels, and the beginings of a button, plus an attempt at value checking with the attached code. My current issue is finding some way of splitting the Entry widgets apart into separate entities with individual names. My current attempt has me trying to feed the keys from testDict into storeDict along with the entry values.

```
    from tkinter import *

data = Tk()

# This sequence controls the label names and by extension the number of 
#widgets in the frame because each one is iterated through the for loop
test_seq = ['Sample1','Sample2','Sample3','Sample4','Sample5',
            'Sample6','Sample7','Sample8','Sample9','Sample10','Sample11',]



class Generator():

    def __init__(self, master, sequence,r,c): #r and c for row and column

       #Take a sequence and turn it into a dictionary with only keys
       testDict = dict.fromkeys(sequence,'' )

       #Set up the save button in the frame
       save_button = Button(master, text='Save Values',command=savevalues)
       save_button.grid(row=r, column=c)

       for key in testDict:
           r=r+1
           c=c
           label = Label(master,text = key + ' :')
           label.grid(row=r, column=c)
           entry = Entry(master)
           entry.bind("<Return>",checknumber("<Return>",entry))
           entry.grid(row =r,column =c+1)
           # storeDict = dict(key,entry.get()) #AN attempt at making a new 
           #dict to store the entry info


           # Limits the size of the frame to 11 rows including 0
           if r==10:
               r=0
               c=c+2
#Beginning of button setup
def savevalues():
        print('Hello, World!')

#Setting up the widgets to only accept float values. Otherwise return ERROR
def checknumber(event,entry):
    print('Hello, again!')
    try:
         float(entry.get())
    except ValueError:
         entry.configure(text= 'ERROR')

testObj = Generator(data, test_seq, 0, 0)

data.mainloop()
```

The code in its current state really shows the problem when it is run because my attempt at setting up a value check has all of the widgets showing the same text because they are all iterations of the variable "entry" in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the binding you are using for validation is the validatecommand feature. It can resolve the issue of validation at the time of user input. [http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry-validation.html](http://validation)

If you use the 'name' property of the Entry widget the output data can be constructed as a dictionary keyed to your input tags which may match your strategy of passing data as a dictionary object.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

ROOT = tk.Tk()
# example validation function
def _potential_float(num):
    max_one_dot = num.count('.') <= 1
    invalid = sum(1 for x in num if x not in '.0123456789')
    if max_one_dot and not invalid:
        return True
    return False
def getall_data():
    # dictionary of data matching test_seq input names
    data = {str(x).split('.')[-1]:x.get() for x in widget_reference}
    print(data)
    return data
test_seq = ['sample1','sample2','sample3','sample4','sample5',
            'sample6','sample7','sample8','sample9','sample10','sample11',]
frame = ttk.Frame(master=ROOT)
frame.grid()
widget_reference = []
# register the validation function
_is_float = frame.register(_potential_float)
# setup your labels and entries
for row, text in enumerate(test_seq):
    ttk.Label(master=frame,
              text=text).grid(column=0,
                              row=row)
    # specify the use of a validatecommand & attach name property
    temp = ttk.Entry(master=frame,
                     name=text,
                     validate='key',
                     validatecommand=(_is_float, '%P'))
    temp.grid(column=1,
              row=row)
    widget_reference.append(temp)
ttk.Button(master=frame,
           command=getall_data,
           text='collect data').grid(column=0,
                                     columnspan=2,
                                     row=11)
ROOT.mainloop()
```